# create an ItemResponse in Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to send an automatic response from code to a form of mine.  I can open it and send empty responses (I create a FormResponse and submit it empty).

Now I want to fill the itemResponses prior to submit.  I'm trying to use

```
FormResponse.withItemResponse(itemResponse)
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response?hl=es-ES#withItemResponse(ItemResponse)
but I can't find a way to create the ItemResponse argument to fill my FormResponse.
I searched the whole documentation, I know there must be a way, but I simply can't find it.

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var response = form.createResponse();
var itemResponse = ????????????;
response.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
response.submit();
```

Any hint?  Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it!

Because Google search "itemresponse" throw me nothing, I finally searched itemresponse in Google for the GAS documentation site...

The only way to create an ItemResponse is from the specific Item typed object.  For example:

```
var itemResponse = TextItem.createResponse('my text');
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item#createResponse(String)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Apps Script interface *Item* does not implement a *createResponse* method. However, the *Item* interface has *as_Item* methods (e.g., *asTextItem()*) that return an instance of TextItem, CheckboxItem, etc., that implements a *createResponse* method.

```js
// This throws "TypeError: item.createResponse is not a function" if
// item is not an instance of a specific item class such as TextItem.
item.createResponse("response")

// The above will throw the error even if the item is a text box.
item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.TEXT

// Once the item is cast into an **instance** of a specific item class,
// it will no longer throw the error.
item.asTextItem().createResponse("response")
```