# How to automate the response of a google-form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have to fill almost every day a google-form for my enterprise. The information are already present on my computer, so I have to open a browser and copy and paste the data in the form.

Before I will write a javascript or python-script, which can do this annoying taste for me, I like to know if there is a google solution, like a API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create an ItemResponse in Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897067/create-an-itemresponse-in-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need script to fill out a form with the same data. Google forms has a built in option to pre-populate the contents. Do you have edit access to the form?

From there you can get a URL https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/FORM_ID/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1347905640=Option+1. See how there is a an entry with a number and then the option to fill them in? The entries are listed in the forms markup also. So if you don't have a edit access you can create the URL yourself.

In the Google form editor there is this option.

[image]