# How do I get Autocrat addon form trigger to work with apps script form

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a regular google spread sheet that triggers a sidebar form apps script Onload:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f8n0eRbUacX218zUTBmrOyPWp3wOpi6tOyU8v2UnQdc/edit?usp=sharing

I need a mail merge to be initiated every time the form is submitted.

I have used the Autocrat addon for this when using Google Forms but I cannot get the form trigger to work when submitting from an apps script form. The time trigger actually works.

I feel like im missing something here, can anyone shed some light on why the form trigger doesn't work in this configuration or perhaps other a suggestion for an alternative approach.

Really appreciate the help
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Only Google Forms will trigger the on form submit trigger, so you should add a Google Form to your spreadsheet and to make that your script create a Google Form response submission.

Related

- [create an ItemResponse in Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16897067/1595451)
- [how to create a google form response with app script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36831901/1595451)